# How to set Microsoft Edge user agent in a domain environment

Tags: group-policy, active-directory

In Microsoft IE11 it's possible to modify the user agent via a registry key, so that we add (for example) "in-Domain" to the UA-string.

How can the same be accomplished in Edge?
Is there any GPO, registry, voodoo to set the user agent in Edge?

I'm well aware, this is possible via F12 Tools, but that's out of scope, since I cannot deploy it centrally.

Answer (score 0):

There are no official (nor supported) ways to change the UserAgent in Microsoft Edge.

However, for testing and development puroposes, you can set the useragent in the registry (since it's not official, this may stop working at any time).

Create two values in this registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\LowRegistry\CustomUserAgent
```

```
Name: CustomUAActive
Type: DWORD
Data: 1
```

```
Name: CustomUA
Type: String
Data: Your-User-Agent
```

Warning: You have to specify the full user-agent !

There are no supported way of modifying the UA centrally. Can you tell us why you want to do this ?